# Why does align: center in the parent mess up my position: absolute overlays?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-position

Could somebody explain why using `display: flex;` `align: center;` in the parent of this menu messes up the two absolutely positioned overlays in a child element?

Here's a fiddle where you can try it with and without `align: center` to get my meaning. (uncomment /* align: center; */ in .menu)

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/wmtr87gc/

```css
body { background-color: gray;}
.menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    /* align-items: center; */
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 0;
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 30%);
}
.menu-item {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: hsl(0, 0%, 70%);
}
.menu-item.progress {
  background-color: gray;
}
.progress-bar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  width: 83%;
  background-color: hsla(191, 58%, 46%, 1);
}
.progress-value {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu-item">Stuff</div>
  <div class="menu-item progress">
    <div class="progress-bar"></div>
    <div class="progress-value">83</div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">Things</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the middle element contains only absolute elements so there is no in-flow content inside it to define its height. Then the default `align-items` is [stretch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items#Values) so your element will get stretched by default and its height will be equal to its parent height BUT if you change the alignment the element will consider its content to define the height and since there no in-flow element it will have `height:0` which means that the progress bar defined by `top:0;bottom:0` will also have height `0`.

To avoid this, keep at least one of the element not positoned (the one that contain the text) so that the middle element have some in-flow content and its height will be different from `0` whataver the alignment will be.

```css
body {
  background-color: gray;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 0;
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 30%);
}

.menu-item {
  position: relative;
  z-index:0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: hsl(0, 0%, 70%);
}

.menu-item.progress {
  background-color: gray;
}

.progress-bar {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 83%;
  background-color: hsla(191, 58%, 46%, 1);
}

.progress-value {
  color: hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu-item">Stuff</div>
  <div class="menu-item progress">
    <div class="progress-bar"></div>
    <div class="progress-value">83</div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">Things</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Happy 50k.